# Expand circle on hover keeping the background centered?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to enlarge a circular element on hover to show more of the background.

I thought I managed to do it however the background moves slightly during the transition, this is what I have now:

http://jsfiddle.net/ANN32/

```
.foto-icono // The container
{
height: 250px;
text-align: center;
}
.foto-icono > div // The image without padding
{
border-radius: 50%;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
padding: 0;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.foto-icono > div:hover // More padding and a negative margin so it stays on the same position
{
padding: 20px;
margin-top: -20px;
}
```

I also tried changing the item height and width on hover (instead of the padding) but I randomly get a weird "tremble" from the background.

How can I do this?

Comment: With firefox, it works just fine - chromium is busted though.

Comment: Here's the thing though, if you resize the fiddle small enough to force a vertical scrollbar, it works just how it should.

Comment: For me it works fine in Chrome (without a scrollbar).

Comment: had some limited success setting background-attachment:fixed but don't have time to play any more :(

Comment: It seems to be smooth only when there are an even number of pixels horizontally. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/ANN32/3/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As opposed to padding, i'd suggest adjusting a transparent border. This eliminates the issue on Chrome.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DE667/)

```
.foto-icono > div {
    border:0px solid transparent;
}
.foto-icono > div:hover {
    border:20px solid transparent;
    margin-top:-20px;
}
```

Comment: I think it's a great idea, however randomly I get the little "shake" I mentioned in the end of my answer. I still see it on the fiddle, but it's more apparent here: http://pranalog.com/test/

Comment: @Liso22 Would you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/G582s/) ? That's a completely different approach

Comment: I wanted to reveal more of the image. Your approach is the best I could get, but though it should work it's still buggy on some browsers, sometimes randomly.

Answer (score 3):

I got it. remove `text-align:center` from your `.foto-icono` class.

here is updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/ANN32/2/